# option for offline voice recognition

Tags: google-gdk

Im using a voice trigger with a prompt, so it drops straight into the voice recognition. When it has trouble recognizing, it goes to the internet. Is there a way to prevent this. ie to have an error when it can't recognize locally on the device (eg an option).

The problem is that using the network takes too long and often fails. This is especially true if the speech was poor. I'd rather ask the user to repeat to say something slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported by Glass but there is a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=305) that you can follow.